# When I console.log type of my function which returns an object it gives undefined. I don't understand why

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why the result of this code is undefined?

```
function f() {
    return
    {
        x: 0
    };
}
console.log(type of f());
```

Comment: `type of` is not an operator, use `typeof` instead. I'm just wondering, how have you managed to avoid to see the error message the code triggers ..?

Comment: Try making your return like this: `return
    {
        x: 0
    };` Then you will return something

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` is a single word. Also, you are invoking your function, thus you are evaluating it's returned value, which is undefined in your code because of automatic semicolon insertion.

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

> The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and the expression.

```js
function f() {
    return //this is treated as though it had a ;
    {
        x: 0
    };
}
console.log(typeof f());
console.log(typeof f);
```

```js
function f() {
    return {
        x: 0
    };
}
console.log(typeof f());
console.log(typeof f);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i understand what was the problem